# Не могу отобразить добавленный через js элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Написал такой код:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let e = document.createElement('svg');

        $(e).attr('fill', 'red');
        $(e).attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
        $(e).attr('viewBox', '0 0 26 26');
        $(e).attr('width', '26px');
        $(e).attr('height', '26px');
        $(e).css('position', 'absolute');

        p = document.createElement("path");
        $(p).attr('d', 'M 20 2.03125 C 19.449219 2.03125 19 2.480469 19 3.03125 L 19 7.8125 L 13.71875 2.53125 C 13.328125 2.140625 12.671875 2.140625 12.28125 2.53125 L 0.5625 14.28125 C 0.171875 14.671875 0.171875 15.296875 0.5625 15.6875 C 0.953125 16.078125 1.578125 16.078125 1.96875 15.6875 L 13 4.65625 L 24.0625 15.71875 C 24.257813 15.914063 24.523438 16.03125 24.78125 16.03125 C 25.039063 16.03125 25.273438 15.914063 25.46875 15.71875 C 25.859375 15.328125 25.859375 14.703125 25.46875 14.3125 L 22 10.84375 L 22 3.03125 C 22 2.480469 21.550781 2.03125 21 2.03125 Z M 13 6.5 L 2 17.5 L 2 23 C 2 24.65625 3.34375 26 5 26 L 21 26 C 22.65625 26 24 24.65625 24 23 L 24 17.5 Z M 11 16 L 15 16 C 15.550781 16 16 16.449219 16 17 L 16 23 C 16 23.550781 15.550781 24 15 24 L 11 24 C 10.449219 24 10 23.550781 10 23 L 10 17 C 10 16.449219 10.449219 16 11 16 Z');
        e.append(p);

        document.body.append(e);
        alert('end');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код должен создать красную иконку домика. Если открыть страницу в браузере то добавляется такой код

```
<svg fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 26 26" width="26px" height="26px" style="position: absolute;">
<path d="M 20 2.03125 C 19.449219 2.03125 19 2.480469 19 3.03125 L 19 7.8125 L 13.71875 2.53125 C 13.328125 2.140625 12.671875 2.140625 12.28125 2.53125 L 0.5625 14.28125 C 0.171875 14.671875 0.171875 15.296875 0.5625 15.6875 C 0.953125 16.078125 1.578125 16.078125 1.96875 15.6875 L 13 4.65625 L 24.0625 15.71875 C 24.257813 15.914063 24.523438 16.03125 24.78125 16.03125 C 25.039063 16.03125 25.273438 15.914063 25.46875 15.71875 C 25.859375 15.328125 25.859375 14.703125 25.46875 14.3125 L 22 10.84375 L 22 3.03125 C 22 2.480469 21.550781 2.03125 21 2.03125 Z M 13 6.5 L 2 17.5 L 2 23 C 2 24.65625 3.34375 26 5 26 L 21 26 C 22.65625 26 24 24.65625 24 23 L 24 17.5 Z M 11 16 L 15 16 C 15.550781 16 16 16.449219 16 17 L 16 23 C 16 23.550781 15.550781 24 15 24 L 11 24 C 10.449219 24 10 23.550781 10 23 L 10 17 C 10 16.449219 10.449219 16 11 16 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Но иконка все равно не появляется. Но если скопировать этот код отдельно и открыть в браузере то иконка появится. Никак не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы в первом случае иконка тоже появлялась.

Comment: ты можешь форматировать новый объект сразу `html`ом в строке(шаблонной), как я [делал тута](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122585/jquery-клонировать-элементы/1122697#1122697)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

createElement => createElementNS

```js
void function () {
  // let e = document.createElement('svg');
  let e = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  
  $(e).attr('fill', 'red');
  $(e).attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
  $(e).attr('viewBox', '0 0 26 26');
  $(e).attr('width', '26px');
  $(e).attr('height', '26px');
  $(e).css('position', 'absolute');

  // let p = document.createElement("path");
  let p = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
  $(p).attr('d', 'M 20 2.03125 C 19.449219 2.03125 19 2.480469 19 3.03125 L 19 7.8125 L 13.71875 2.53125 C 13.328125 2.140625 12.671875 2.140625 12.28125 2.53125 L 0.5625 14.28125 C 0.171875 14.671875 0.171875 15.296875 0.5625 15.6875 C 0.953125 16.078125 1.578125 16.078125 1.96875 15.6875 L 13 4.65625 L 24.0625 15.71875 C 24.257813 15.914063 24.523438 16.03125 24.78125 16.03125 C 25.039063 16.03125 25.273438 15.914063 25.46875 15.71875 C 25.859375 15.328125 25.859375 14.703125 25.46875 14.3125 L 22 10.84375 L 22 3.03125 C 22 2.480469 21.550781 2.03125 21 2.03125 Z M 13 6.5 L 2 17.5 L 2 23 C 2 24.65625 3.34375 26 5 26 L 21 26 C 22.65625 26 24 24.65625 24 23 L 24 17.5 Z M 11 16 L 15 16 C 15.550781 16 16 16.449219 16 17 L 16 23 C 16 23.550781 15.550781 24 15 24 L 11 24 C 10.449219 24 10 23.550781 10 23 L 10 17 C 10 16.449219 10.449219 16 11 16 Z');
  e.append(p);

  document.body.append(e);
}()

// fix
function $(element) {
  return {
    attr(a, v) {
      element.setAttribute(a, v)
    },
    css(s, v) {
      element.style[s] = v
    }
  }
}
```